# Increasing size of mouse pointer affected click area beyond 1x1 pixel?

Tags: mouse, touchscreen, input-devices, xinput, input

is it possible to increase the size of the mouse pointer click area?

The click area seems to be 1x1 pixel only. Would it be possible to increase it?

So that the click area would be increased to 5x5 pixel for example (i.e the click affects 5x5 pixel for example)?

This could probably increase touchscreen usability.

The only thing I could find on Google was the following thread, which did not provide an answer:

[Increase the pointer area | Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=114091)

Comment: I'm going to say no, because (1) all the underlying events describe mouse clicks at a single x,y point and (2) if your 5x5 pixel click area covered two widgets, which would you send the event to? But there must be other things to improve touch screen usability